# JList values appear in applet viewer, but not in the applet ( in browser)

Tags: java, swing, applet, jlist

> A string is being input by the user in the applet.
>   That string is then chopped up into smaller strings and loaded into an array A1.
>   JList values in listbox appear in the applet viewer.  But not in the applet.
>   JList is in Panel2.  What is blocking the values in the applet?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class QueryWindow extends JApplet{

JTextField textField;
JButton button, button2; 
JLabel label, label2 ;
JList<String> listbox ;
JPanel thePanel;
JPanel Panel1, Panel2;
DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

public void init(){

GridBagLayout layout =new GridBagLayout();
thePanel = new JPanel();
thePanel.setLayout(layout);

GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
```

> Define the x,y positions of the components
>   Two panels used.  Panel2 holds the JList component.

```
gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridConstraints.gridy = 0;

gridConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
gridConstraints.gridheight = 1;

gridConstraints.weightx = 10;
gridConstraints.weighty = 10;

gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

gridConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

textField = new JTextField(" ", 60);
Font font =new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
textField.setFont(font);

button = new JButton("Enter Your Query");

label = new JLabel(" ");


thePanel.add(textField, gridConstraints);
gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
gridConstraints.gridx = 62;
thePanel.add(button, gridConstraints);
gridConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
thePanel.add(label, gridConstraints);

gridConstraints.gridwidth = 3;
gridConstraints.gridheight = 20;
gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridConstraints.gridy = 3;
gridConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;  //BOTH


Panel2 = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
label2 = new JLabel("Annotations ");
Panel2.add(label2);  

listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
listbox = new JList<String>(listModel);  

listbox.setVisibleRowCount(10);

listbox.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

Panel2.add(new JScrollPane(listbox));  

thePanel.add(Panel2, gridConstraints);
```

> create an object that will monitor the button click

```
GetResultsListener butListener = new GetResultsListener();
button.addActionListener(butListener);

this.add(thePanel);
this.setVisible(true);

}
```

> Press the Query button to call the REST based method, to chop up long string.

```
class GetResultsListener implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

String textFieldText = textField.getText();
ArrayList<String> A1 = new ArrayList<String>();
listModel.clear();   


textField.setText(textFieldText);
```

> REST based code is called to annotate longer string
>    The queryToAnnotate method returns string values in array A1.  I force print the contents of A1
>    on the screen.  I assign the values in A1 to listModel.  The applet viewer correctly displays the >  values in JList. 
>    But the JList box is empty in the applet.

```
AnnotateQuery annotateQuery =new AnnotateQuery();

try {
     annotateQuery.queryToAnnotate(textFieldText, A1);

     for (int h=0; h<A1.size(); h++)

      {                 
          listModel.addElement(A1.get(h));    

      }


     } 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        //         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }



Panel2.repaint();   
A1.clear();

}

}

}
}
```

Comment: Does the applet have permission to make network connection? You may also want to have a read of [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Its not a signed applet.  I just created an http, not https.  Is this what you mean by permission?

Comment: Take a look at [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer and Andrew Thompson.  This helps me rewrite things.

Comment: Can I substitute the applet with HTML form for user input, and a java server page?